# Why I have issuse with redirect() after I call app()->handle($request)

Tags: laravel-8

I try to call internal JWT API for check token(expired or not..) and I stored token in browser session

```
public function index(){ 
        $check = $this->check_login();
        
        if($check != 1){
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
        return view('main_pages.home');
    }
 function check_login(){
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
          }
          
          $token = $_SESSION['token'];
          $request = Request::create('/api/user', 'POST');
          $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
          $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$token);
          
          $response = app()->handle($request);
          $res = json_decode($response->getContent()); // convert to json object
        return $res->status;
    }
```

when I got `$res->status = 0;` it's redirect to `localhost/login` (without port) this issuse come from when I called `app()->handle($resquest)`

So how can I `redirect('login')` after I accessed to internal JWT API by `app()->handle($resquest)`
or have another way to access to internal JWT API and then redirect some route

Comment: What is the "issue" you are facing? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I can't redirect to login route, this problem come after I call app()->handle() for access internal API. so how can I redirect ?or  have another way for access to JWT API internal ?

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it